# Android - получить путь к файлу из Intent

Tags: android, java, файлы

Пытаюсь научить своё приложение научить открывать текст и видео. Вызываю `startActivityForResult(...)`, в `onActivityResult(...)` мне возвращается путь к файлу, но он имеет вид типа `content://com.estrongs.explorer/493942.txt`.

Как мне получить полный абсолютный путь к файлу?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String name = intent.getData().getEncodedPath();
```

Comment: Немного не так, но сработало.

Comment: почему то не работает для андроид 10  выдает /document/audio%3A43101